# Setting aspx table's visibility to true fails

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm puzzled here. I have a webform with 3 tables in it. I want to show/hide them according to certain conditions. It all works fine except in one situation.

this is what I have:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upGeneral" runat="server" >
    <ContentTemplate>

        <table id="tab1" runat="server" visible="true" width="100%">
           ...
        </table>
        <table id="tab2" runat="server" visible="false" width="100%">
           ...
        </table>
        <table id="tab3" runat="server" visible="false" width="100%">
           ...
        </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

then, I have a few buttons added to the page, and depending on which one is pressed, I'll change the table's visibility.
My problem is that, under certain conditions, I'm changing tab3's visibility to true, and tab1 and tab2's to false, and while tab1 will have it's visibility set to false, tab3 will not have it's visibility set to true... sigh!

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        ...
        if (!editMode)
        {
            tab1.Visible = false;
            tab2.Visible = false;
            tab3.Visible = true;
        }
     }
}
```

in debug mode, as I go through these instructions, tab3.visibile = true will not change tab3's property!
Has this happened to you before? How did you solve it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The code and concept seem fine. Is it possible you have more than one element named tab3?

Comment: No. Just one. It's puzzling because it works fine in the button I have to show it. However, on this instance, I want to show tab3 right upon page load

Comment: So as you step through when you load the page for the first time it definetly hits that line but produces the wrong effect (i.e. not showing table 3). Is there any css or statement elsewhere that may be overriding the function you are calling after the page load call?

Comment: I wonder if the action button is inside the Update Panel. If it is in other Update Panel you need to add it in the triggers list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could lie with the update panel.

If you are trying to update content from outside of the update panel then you will need to specify the control that will update the panel in the post back element of the panel

```
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click">
```

Without specifying the trigger then the update panel won't update the properties within it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's possible that your problem lies here:

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
```

This will cause the `statement` inside the `if condition` to be ran only *once* - when the page
is firstly loaded.

When a postback is issued (i.e you pressed a button), this statement won't be reached.

Try changing to

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
```

Comment: The code he shows is only meant to set a default to the page and so he only needs it to run once when the page is loaded for the first time.